# -sentenceDelimiter newline in java API

Tags: java, nlp, tokenize

I can run POS tagger from command line to preserve new line as

```
java -classpath stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model models/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger -sentenceDelimiter newline -textFile input.txt > output.txt
```

given parameter "-sentenceDelimiter newline". But I wonder how can I do in java program using API?

I saw in FAQ, that we can set ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak, but no idea how to set it.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

I want to tag this kind of sentence in single line.

```
 "what is your name?" he asked.
```

since a line might contain many sentences marker.

Thank a lot.
Shrestha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ssplit.eolonly` property. According to the [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage), it means "only split sentences on newlines. Works well in conjunction with '-tokenize.whitespace true', in which case StanfordCoreNLP will treat the input as one sentence per line, only separating words on whitespace."

```
props.setProperty("ssplit.eolonly", "true");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```